# Is XML declaration needed in XSLT files?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"...
```

It does not start with XML declaration.

By standard:

> Because each XML entity not accompanied by external encoding information and not in UTF-8 or UTF-16 encoding must begin with an XML
>   encoding declaration, in which the first characters must be '< ?xml',
>   any conforming processor can detect, after two to four octets of
>   input, which of the following cases apply.

...and in [section 2.8](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-prolog-dtd) we get the production for `prolog`:

```
[22]    prolog     ::=       XMLDecl? Misc* (doctypedecl Misc*)?
[23]    XMLDecl    ::=      '<?xml' VersionInfo EncodingDecl? SDDecl? S? '?>'
```

So, we can *omit* the XML declaration, but we can't prefix it with anything.

So I can omit it and the transformation do well but is it a good practice? Can I hit unpredictable situation when have Cyrillic or Chinese symbols for example?

Answer (score 4):

Lexically, the XML declaration is optional for all XML files, including XSLT.

Semantically, it is required for XML 1.1 (and beyond) and encodings other than UTF-8 or UTF-16. (Technically, an XML declaration is still optional for other than UTF-8 or UTF-16 if [*an encoding is determined by a higher-level protocol*](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#NT-EncodingDecl), but for clarity of intent, you ought to use an XML declaration if possible consistently in such cases too.)